# Excel - Looking for empty cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way of searching through a range of cells within an Excel spreadsheet column to find any blank cells.
The column will contain "Quantity ordered" and if it remains blank then it throws up errors later on in a different system. If I can detect the error now I can mark that sheet as failed so it can be manually processed or queried with the customer.

I have tried various methods but keep either receiving the error "Conversion from type 'Object(,)' to type 'String' is not valid" or it will just ignore the code.

The first bit of code finds the last used row in the worksheet so the following code only looks from row 2 column 8 to the last used row of column 8:

```
Dim rw As Integer = 1
            Do Until xlNewWorkSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value Is Nothing
                rw += 1
            Loop
            Dim last As String = rw - 1
            'Dim quantity As String

            Dim xlRange As Excel.Range = Nothing
            xlRange = xlNewWorkSheet.Range(xlNewWorkSheet.Cells(2, 8), xlNewWorkSheet.Cells(last, 8))

            For Each qcell As Excel.Range In xlRange.Cells
                If qcell.Value <> "" Then
                    MsgBox("Empty value found in quantity...exiting...")
                End If
            Next
            With xlNewWorkSheet.Range("A1:Z100")
                'quantity = (.Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(last, 8)).Value)
                'If quantity Is Nothing Then
                'MsgBox("Empty value found in quantity...exiting...")
                'Else
                .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(last, 1)).Value = (Cust + "_" + dt2)
                'End If

            End With
```

Ideally I want to enter further error checking of the rows and columns for any other anomalies, for example I sometimes get spreadsheets with #REF! in them so deleting those rows would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the `SpecialCells`property for the range to find the empty cells without looping, all at once.

Comment: Hi Damian. How would I use that in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just something you can adapt. Count if there is any empty cell. IF the count is 0, means everything is ok. If not, something is wrong

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim TotalBlanks As Long
TotalBlanks = 0
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'change this with your target range

On Error Resume Next
TotalBlanks = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
On Error GoTo 0

If TotalBlanks > 0 Then
    'there is blanks, so do what you want and exit or end
    Debug.Print "There is blanks"
    End
End If

'rest of code if there is not a single blank
Debug.Print "Everything is ok"
Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

If I run the code above with previous data example, I get output [image]

[image]

If I run the code above with previous data example, I get output [image] and it quits

Comment: This worked thanks. I adapted it slightly to fint my current code but it did the job